# How to access control in UpdatePanel through javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

How to access or get reference of control in `UpdatePanel` through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control in an `UpdatePanel` is no different than a control on any other page so you can access them in the same way.  The difference is that an `UpdatePanel` can have new controls added constantly with no easy way for you to get the `ClientID` of the control on the fly as the `UpdatePanel` updates.  In these cases I have used a unique style name (style doesn't have to have any details, it's just used as a tag in this case) and access it using [jQuery's](http://www.jquery.com)  style accessor.  It's not very often that I have to resort to this method but when I have had to style names were sufficient.

```
// Will get the control with this specific style
$(".YourControlsUniqueStyleName")
```

**EDIT:**

In your control add the following to the CssClass:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="YourControlsUniqueStyleName"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then with javascript using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) you can access the control with the css class name directly like so and read the value:

```
var TextBox1Value = $(".YourControlsUniqueStyleName").val();
```

Hope that helps.